# Use of FlareController in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flare

I have a flare file containing two animations:
https://www.2dimensions.com/a/Azhar/files/flare/google_loader/preview

I want both animations to play one after another on clicking a single button once.
I did some research and found that `FlareController` can help me in this but I am unable to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted to do?

Comment: Somewhat yes! Take a look at this custom flare controller: https://github.com/mdazharuddin1011999/Anweshan-Quiz/blob/master/lib/utils/custom_flare_controller.dart

Comment: This is the flare file: https://www.2dimensions.com/a/Azhar/files/flare/google_loader